# Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function, with continuous derivate in $[a,b]$ such that:

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

$0<f'(x)<M \ \ \forall \ x\in[a,b]$

Find $c,d\in R$ such that $c\leq f(x)\leq d$.

Comment: No bound of this type is possible. If $f$ satisfies your assumptions, so does $f+C$.

Comment: @Federico: Can we show the same for $c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ in general? or $c,d\in[a,b]$ only?

Comment: Why should $c,d\in[a,b]$? $a$ and $b$ define the domain, $c$ and $d$ are to be thought in the codomain

Comment: My previous comment says that you cannot have bounds $c(a,b,M)$ and $d(a,b,M)$ depending only on the given data

Comment: What you can have is of course $\left|\max\limits_{[a,b]}f-\min\limits_{[a,b]}f\right|\leq M(b-a)$.

Comment: Given that $f'\geq0$, this is equivalent to $f(b)-f(a)\leq M(b-a)$.

Comment: But you cannot have an upper bound on $f$ depending just on $a,b,M$.

Comment: This question is from a list of exercises, I thought I had few details to find c and d...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) the function $f$ admits at least a maximum and a minimum on $[a,b]$. Since $f'>0$, the function is strictly increasing and takes extreme values at the bounds of the interval of definition. Then $c=f(a)$ and $d=f(b)$.

Comment: And these are the best bounds for $f$ attains them. Curious how other answers, which are ok but just ok got the points.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$f'$ is continuous at $[a,b[$, by integration

$$(\forall x\in[a,b]) \;\; 0<f'(x)<M\implies$$
$$0 \leq\int_a^xf'(t)dt<M\int_a^xdt \implies$$
$$0 \leq f(x)-f(a)<M(x-a)\implies$$
$$f(a) \leq f(x)<M(b-a)+f(a)$$

Answer (score 0):

If you know a bit of general topology, there is an easy proof of a stronger statement:

*Lemma.* Let $(X, \tau), (Y, \sigma)$ be topological spaces and let $f \colon (X, \tau) \to (Y, \sigma)$ be continuous. If $C$ is compact in $(X,\tau)$. Then $f[C]$ is compact in $(Y, \sigma)$.

Prove this and combine it with the fact that $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if it is closed and bounded.